# E. Fradkin on thermal propagator of free scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator, textbook-erratum, thermal-field-theory

In his [lecture](https://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/582-chapter5-edited.pdf), E. Fradkin performs a [Matsubara sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency) to show that the finite temperature contribution to the thermal propagator of the free scalar field contains the Bose-Einstein factor (see 5.209 - 218 in the lecture)
$$
n(\mathbf{p},T)=\left[ \exp\left( \frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}}{T} \right) -1 \right]^{-1}.
$$
However, the author's result (5.215) of the frequency sum seems incorrect to me, which I discussed in a Math StackExchange [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035557/matsubara-sum-arising-from-qft-and-contour-integral/4036658#4036658). If the conclusion there is correct, (5.215) should be rewritten as (with $\omega_{\mathbf{p}}=\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$)
$$
G_T(\mathbf{x},\tau)
= \int \frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^d} \left\{
\frac{\coth\left(\frac{\omega_{\mathbf{p}}}{2T}\right)}{2\omega_{\mathbf{p}}}\cosh{\left(\omega_{\mathbf{p}}\tau\right)}-\sinh{\left(\omega_{\mathbf{p}}\tau\right)}
\right\} e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}},
$$
which reduces for small $\tau$ to
$$
G_T(\mathbf{x},\tau)
\simeq \int \frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^d}
\frac{\coth\left(\frac{\omega_{\mathbf{p}}}{2T}\right)}{2\omega_{\mathbf{p}}} \frac{1}{2} \left[ e^{\omega_{\mathbf{p}}\tau}+e^{-\omega_{\mathbf{p}}\tau} \right]
 e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}.
$$
But then the real-time propagator (5.218) would be
$$
G^{(0)}(\mathbf{x};T)=G_M^{(0)}(\mathbf{x})
+ \int \frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{n(\mathbf{p},T)}{\omega_{\mathbf{p}}} \frac{1}{2} \left[ e^{i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}x_0}+e^{-i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}x_0} \right] e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}},
$$
where
$$
G_M^{(0)}(\mathbf{x})
= \int \frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^d 2\omega_{\mathbf{p}}} \frac{1}{2} \left[ e^{i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}x_0}+e^{-i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}x_0} \right] e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
\neq \int \frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^d 2\omega_{\mathbf{p}}} e^{-i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}|x_0|} e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
$$
is not the real-time propagator at $T=0$ (the correct expression for propagator can be found, for example, on page 24, Zee, [[Nutshell](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691140346/quantum-field-theory-in-a-nutshell)]).

How do I fix this apparent inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also derive @Svyatoslav's correct expression   by Poisson Summation:
$$
 \frac 1{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+M^2}=
   \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty   \frac 1{2|M |} e^{-|M||\tau+2\pi n|}, \quad \hbox{(Poisson Summation)}\\
   =  \frac 1 {2M} \frac{\cosh(\pi -\tau)M}{\sinh \pi M}, \quad 0<\tau<2\pi,\nonumber
$$
The first line come from applying Poisson summation to the zero temperature expression
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{e^{ik\tau}} {k^2+M^2}=\frac 1 {2|M|}e^{-|\tau||M|} 
$$
and has the  physical interpretation as  the method-of-images sum over the  $n$-fold winding of the particle trajectory around the periodic imaginary time direction.
The passage from the first  to second  lines is just summing  the two  geometric series from  $n=0$ to $ \infty$ and $n=-\infty$ to $-1$.

I saw  Eduardo while out walking yesterday, and informed him  of the problem. I  expect that he will fix his notes.